# unable to get flot graph to display

Tags: javascript, flot

I'm trying to create a plot of temperature change over a period of time, so to start off, I'm trying to get a graph up with some test data plotted on it, but none of the data seems to want to show. I'm a bit new to JavaScript and flot, so I tried piecing together the needed code based off of seeing how other people created graphs in flot.

The data for the time on the x-axis, I created in the code just to have something to plot the temperature against, whilst I retrieved the temperature data from a .json file with test data in it. Getting the data points into a set to pass into the plot function seems to be coming together okay, but I just can't get a display. Instead, all I get is what is shown in the image that I will display after my code. Could anyone please let me know what I did wrong or what I'm missing? I'm honestly stumped here.

Source code (made by editing a flot example page):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 <title>Flot Examples: Resizing</title>
 <link href="../examples.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <link href="../shared/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <!--[if lte IE 8]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../excanvas.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery.js"></script>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../shared/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery.flot.js"></script>

 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery.flot.time.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">

 
 $(document).ready(function() {


  //Creating an array to hold the plot data
  var plotdata = new Array();

  $.getJSON('test_data.json', function (data) {

   //Creating a base date to make times off of
   var basedate = new Date("February 20, 2017 08:00");

  for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
   var datepoint = new Date(basedate.getTime() + 600000*i).getTime();
   switch(i) {

    case 0:
    var temppoint = data["node 10"][0]["2017-02-22 20:00"][0];
    break;

    case 1:
    var temppoint = data["node 10"][0]["2017-02-18 22:50"][0];
    break;

    case 2:
    var temppoint = data["node 10"][0]["2017-02-20 22:00"][0];
    break;

    case 3:
    var temppoint = data["node 10"][0]["2017-02-20 13:50"][0];
    break;

    case 4:
    var temppoint = data["node 10"][0]["2017-02-19 7:00"][0];
    break;

    case 5:
    var temppoint = data["node 10"][0]["2017-02-21 15:30"][0];
    break;

    case 6:
    var temppoint = data["node 10"][0]["2017-02-18 3:50"][0];
    break;

    case 7:
    var temppoint = data["node 10"][0]["2017-02-16 5:20"][0];
    break;

    case 8:
    var temppoint = data["node 10"][0]["2017-02-19 6:10"][0];
    break;

    case 9:
    var temppoint = data["node 10"][0]["2017-02-16 0:40"][0];
    break;
   }
   //plotdata[i] = [datepoint, temppoint];
   plotdata.push(new Array(datepoint, temppoint));
  }
  console.log(plotdata)

  }) //End of getJSON

  var dataset = [
  {
   label: "temperature",
   data: plotdata
  }
   ];//End of var dataset declaration


  $.plot($("#placeholder"), dataset, {
   series: {
    lines: { show: true },
    points: {show: true },
   },
   grid: {
    hoverable: true,
    clickable: true
   },
   xaxis:
   {
    mode: "time",
    timeformat: "%h: %M\n %m/%d/%y",
    min: (new Date("2017/02/19")).getTime(),
    max: (new Date("2017/02/21")).getTime()
   },

   yaxis:
   {
    min: 50, max: 100, tickSize: 5
   }
  });

 }) //End of (document).ready

 </script>
</head>
<body>

 <div id="content">

  <div class="demo-container">
   <div id="placeholder" class="demo-placeholder"></div>
  </div>

 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is what results from the code:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEuDF.jpg

Any insights as to what I can do to fix this would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323) for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the problem was that the plot function was outside of the .getJSON function. As someone whose main programming knowledge is based on C, I assumed that having the plotdata variable outside of the .getJSON function tied it to that scope, but after the end of .getJSON, the plotdata variable showed to have a size of 0, instead of the 10 points of test data that I set into it in the .getJSON function.

To fix this, I just moved the plot function into the .getJSON function, and now it keeps the changes made to plotdata and displays the proper graph.